# How can I install python-opencv package in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: apt, package-management, python, pip

I am trying to install python-opencv. I can see a distribution for Ubuntu 18.04 right here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python-opencv

Unfortunately, Ubuntu 20.04 can't see it:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-opencv
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-opencv
```

How do I overcome this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should remember that Ubuntu 20.04 uses python3 by default, because python 2 is considered deprecated.

That's why you should install this package using

```bsh
sudo apt-get install python3-opencv
```

But if you really want to use python2 version of this library you can download it using this command

```bsh
python2 -m pip install opencv-python
```

Comment: I am worried that the python 3 version will fail somewhere down the line in this tutorial I'm working through: https://github.com/RedisGears/EdgeRealtimeVideoAnalytics

Comment: I think it is worth trying to do it using python3.

Comment: I have also added another option if you really want to stick with 2.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: I use Ubuntu 20.04, but the above command for python3 dint install opencv for me. No error msg was shown either. Is there anyother way?